# What is a good way of cleaning up after a unit test in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, rust

Since the test-function aborts on a failure, one cannot simply clean up at the end of the function under test.

From testing frameworks in other languages, there's usually a way to setup a callback that handles cleanup at the end of each test-function.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Since the test-function aborts on a failure, one cannot simply clean up at the end of the function under test.

Use RAII and implement `Drop`. It removes the need to call *anything*:

```
struct Noisy;

impl Drop for Noisy {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("I'm melting! Meeeelllllttttinnnng!");
    }
}

#[test]
fn always_fails() {
    let my_setup = Noisy;
    assert!(false, "or else...!");
}
```

```
running 1 test
test always_fails ... FAILED

failures:

---- always_fails stdout ----
    thread 'always_fails' panicked at 'or else...!', main.rs:12
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
I'm melting! Meeeelllllttttinnnng!


failures:
    always_fails

test result: FAILED. 0 passed; 1 failed; 0 ignored; 0 measured
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without polluting the source? Are there any frameworks that are good for this?

Comment: @VladyVeselinov You declare the struct and impl within the test function.

Comment: @VladyVeselinov have a look at https://crates.io/search?q=scope%20guard and pick one that suits your needs.

Comment: How could this be applied for async calls?

Comment: @TamilVendhanKanagarasu unfortunately, "async drop" is a complicated matter. In some cases, you can spin up a lightweight reactor (like [one from the futures crate](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/executor/fn.block_on.html)) to perform the async operation.

Comment: May I make the obvious remark that the elegance of this is that it leverages Rust's own most basic scoping rules to do an essential task specific for testing for which other languages might indeed need a framework?

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the mighty Shepmaster's brilliant solution, and partly in answer to the comment by Vlady Veselinov that this in some way means introducing "superfluous" code into your test, I offer this idea of a "general purpose" Noisy where you stipulate only the cleanup closure you need:

```
struct Noisy<'a> {
    closure: &'a dyn Fn() -> (),
}

impl Noisy<'_> {
    fn new(closure: &dyn Fn() -> ()) -> Noisy {
        Noisy {
            closure,
        }
    }
}

impl Drop for Noisy<'_> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let _ = &(self.closure)();
    }
}

// the idea with this test is that some files are created in a temporary dir
// and must be deleted regardless of outcome at the end of the test...
#[test]
fn index_gather_documents_does_that() -> Result<()>{
    let dir = env::temp_dir();
    let delivered_temp_dir_path = dir.as_path();
    let temp_rust_testing_dir_path = delivered_temp_dir_path.join("rust_testing");
    let cleanup_dir_path = temp_rust_testing_dir_path.clone();
    let cleanup_dir_path_str = cleanup_dir_path.to_str().ok_or_else(
        ||{anyhow!("str failure! |{:?}|", cleanup_dir_path)})?;
    
    let _ = Noisy::new(&||{
        let _ = std::fs::remove_dir_all(cleanup_dir_path_str);
    });

    // ... test proper: start creating the files
```

A desirable refinement might be to return `Result<()>` instead of `()`, because if cleanup code fails you'd generally want that not to be silent: it should usually mean that the test fails, I think...